# Can't set canvas size with getComputedStyle function

Tags: javascript, css, html, canvas

So, the problem is that the `getComputedStyle` function works really strange. Firstly I get my canvas by ID, like `var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas')` then use the `getComputedStyle` function, 
and try to set the new width and height values. But the thing is that it ignores height, and only takes width.

JavaScript:

```
var newCanvas = getComputedStyle(canvas)

var width = parseInt(newCanvas.getPropertyValue('width'), 10)
var height = parseInt(newCanvas.getPropertyValue('height'), 10)

canvas.height = height
canvas.width = width
```

HTML:

```
<canvas id="canvas" width="480" height="320"></canvas>
```

CSS:

```
canvas {
    display: block;
    margin: 10px auto;
    border: 3px solid black;
    border-radius: 10px;
    height: 50%;
    width: 75%;
}
```

When I change the height value (in CSS file), it doesn't affect the size of the canvas. But when I change width value, both width and height change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't rely on `getComputedStyle` since it might be handled inconsistently across browsers. Instead, just use `canvas.offsetWidth` and `canvas.offsetHeight`.

Also note there is a distinction between canvas size attributes and canvas style. Canvas `width` and `height` command how big the drawing area is whereas the style merely changes how big the output is. If you think of the canvas as an image (which is essentially how the browser treats it), it has a width and height but also you can control how to stretch/position it using css properties.

[**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/rejdpnf8/1/)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But `offsetWidth` and `offsetHeight` don't do the trick :(
I try to draw on the canvas using the mouse, and I use `getComputedStyle` to change the size of the canvas everytime the size of the window is changed.

Comment: Maybe I don't understand your requirements? I made a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rejdpnf8/1/) for you.

Comment: You heard me right. And `offsetWidth` with `offsetHeight` really change the size of the canvas dynamically. But the problem is that this way of changing canvas size breaks the mouse position (when I click on canvas and start to draw, the "drawing" start position differs from the position of the mouse). This is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9n13z658) with my project. And it works if I use `getComputedStyle`. The thing is that it just ignores `height` in CSS, you can delete it but the whole thing still would work :D

Comment: It doesn't ignore it. Because it's a percentage, height is calculated based on the parent's size. This is true for any HTML block-level element. Since you haven't explicitly set the size of your body, it just fits to content. Add `html, body { height: 100%; }` at the top of your stylesheet.

Comment: Thank you so much! Now it works perfect! You also answered my first question at Stackoveflow, I really appreciate it!

Comment: Don't worry about it :) Happy coding